# Get ngFor input values to use in .ts?

Tags: angular, ngfor, ngmodel

I have this HTML list generating inputs

```html
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="form-group" *ngFor="let checkNum of checkNums; let n=index">
            Check #{{checkNum}}: $<input name="check{{checkNum}}" type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" placeholder="0.00" />
        </li>
    </ul>
```

What I would like to do is take the value of each generated input field and add them together so that I can get a value to do other stuff with in my `app.compoment.ts` file. The way I'm familiar with doing this is using `[(ngModel)]`, but I can't figure out how to do this when the input is generated by `*ngFor`

EDIT: I solved this by declaring:

`check:number[]=[];`

in my `app.component.ts` file. I don't know if this is best practice but it fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bind it by index

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="check[n]"  name="check{{checkNum}}" type="number" min="0.01" step="0.01" placeholder="0.00" />
```

Comment: This isn't working, I get a bunch of repeated "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" errors when I added this to my `input`s

Comment: If you don't have a property it cannot bind.

Comment: I'm not entirely what this means or how to resolve it, I apologize.

EDIT: Nevermind, had to declare `check:number[]=[];` in my `app.component.ts` first